# OWASP Zap Report for scan Http request

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, httprequest, http

[image]

Hi Friends ,

anyone heard about OWASP Zap Report ?? Scan request and response.
i want create repohttps://eti-massemail.na24.visual.force.com/apex/MassEmail
rt for one app of Salesforce.
i face an issue in that.

1.) Browser XSS Protection is not enabled
2.)  X-Content-Type-Options header  missing

how can i resolve please help me if anyone know ??